# NodeJS memory leak

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, socket.io

I'm making a game with `socket.io` and `mysql`, and at every client connect, I check if the user is banned by IP with **my custom MySQL  function**:

```
MySQL.Query('SELECT * FROM bans WHERE user = ?', username, function(rows) {
    // do something
})
```

but when I connect **> 5** clients, I have this error on the server console:

```
(node) warning: possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11 error listeners added. Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit.
Trace
    at PoolConnection.addListener (events.js:239:17)
    at C:\Users\user\Documents\_server\mysql\mysql.js:26:21
    at Ping.onOperationComplete [as _callback] (C:\Users\user\node_modules\mysql\lib\Pool.js:99:5)
    at Ping.Sequence.end (C:\Users\user\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\sequences\Sequence.js:96:24)
    at Ping.Sequence.OkPacket (C:\Users\user\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\sequences\Sequence.js:105:8)
    at Protocol._parsePacket (C:\Users\user\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Protocol.js:280:23)
    at Parser.write (C:\Users\user\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Parser.js:73:12)
    at Protocol.write (C:\Users\user\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Protocol.js:39:16)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (C:\Users\user\node_modules\mysql\lib\Connection.js:96:28)
    at emitOne (events.js:77:13)
```

**Here's mysql.js file** :

```
var config = require('../config.js');
var mysql = require('mysql');
var pool = mysql.createPool({
    connectionLimit : 100,
    host     : config.sqlhost,
    user     : config.sqluser,
    password : config.sqlpass,
    database : config.sqlbase,
    debug    :  false
});
var MySQL = {
    Query: function(req, reqvars, callback) {
        pool.getConnection(function(err,connection){
            if (err) {
              connection.release();
              console.log('[MySQL] Error while connecting to the database');
            }   
            connection.query(req, reqvars, function(err,rows){
                connection.release();
                if (typeof callback == 'function') callback(rows);
            });
            connection.on('error', function(err) {      
                console.log('[MySQL] Error while attempting query');   
            });
        });
    }, 
}
module.exports = MySQL;
```

*Where's the problem?*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Node.js warns you whenever you attach more than 10 (the default) listeners for the same event on a single event emitter.

In your particular case, you attach an `error` listener to the `connection` object each and every time you make an SQL query. This is probably not what you want, because if the first x queries executed fine, but then one fails, those `error` handlers for the previous queries will still get called.

### Remedy

While I have no practical experience with the mysql library, the first thing hitting me is that you are completely ignoring the `err` parameter of your `connection.query()` callback. You *must not* ignore these, unless you would like to spend hours of debugging a seemingly valid piece of code.

It would seem that instead of attaching an `error` handler to the `connection`, you simply check the `err` argument.

> PS. It is common practice to always pass along any errors that occur during execution as the first argument in callback-based APIs (specifying `null` in case of no error). Your `callback` function seems to not adhere to this practice.

Comment: Thanks, problem solved, I've just checked if err == null to call callback ;)